# Device goes into bootloop

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

My device goes into bootloop, and I don't know, why this is happening?.

Device Details:

> PHONE:  Samsung Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360HU
>
> Recovery:  TWRP
>
> ROM:  CM12.1
>
> Android Version:  Android 5.1.1 Lollipop

I think, this happened, when I changed the theme of the device. After that, the device powered off due to low battery. Then, I charged the device, and powered it on, and it goes into `boot-loop`.

Comment: go to recovery mode and try cleaning cache

Comment: Nope.  This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

*I accidentally found the solution*

Since, doing a Factory Reset (wiping `Data`, `Cache`, and `Dalvik`) does not solve the problem, I also wiped the `System` partition of the device.

So, that would be, wiping `Data`, `Cache`, `Dalvik`, and `System`.

After wiping, download your stock ROM (in this case, CyanogenMod), and place it on your SD Card, using another device.

Then, go into `Recovery Mode`, and flash that stock ROM on your device.

Reboot, and everything should be fine now.

You might, as well, want to install GApps for your device.